# AWS Codebuild containers very very SLOW

Tags: mysql, symfony, amazon-web-services, phpunit, aws-codebuild

I just setup my **Codebuild** pipeline for PHP Symfony2 testing by phpunit.

---

**Situation :**
Some of our tests talk to a local Database (classic mysql-server)

*Codebuild* use our Custom Docker image that is based on `php:5.6-apache`
`OS : Linux Alpine 
PHP VERSION : 5.6`

We execute these steps :

1. Pull sources
2. Setup database (All okey no latency)
3. Composer install (**5 min**)
4. `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`
5. `php app/console broadway:event-store:schema:init`
6. Launch *phpUnit*.

On local environment (Docker with 6GB RAM Allow) everything is okey.
The whole process takes like **15 Minutes**... perfect.

---

**Problem :**

When i launch the build on the same image on **AWS-CodeBuild** this is very much longer :

1. Pull sources (**Instant**)
2. Setup database (**Instant**)
3. Composer install (**5min**)
4. `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`(**14 min**)
5. `php app/console broadway:event-store:schema:init` (**Instant**)
6. *phpUnit* (**Infinity** CodeBuild timeout)

---

**Hypothesis :**
It seems like all php process that access to the DB is super slow.
Classic MySQL requests have a 'normal' speed...

If someone got an idea ?
Thanks for your help
@Rops42

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you first to confirm your hypothesis - since it could be the most likely issue - by enabling MySQL logs (Error Log, General Log, and Slow Queries Log) in your build process and analyze them during or after the build.

If you don't find anything relevant that explains the slowness in those log files, you could use something like [Blackfire](https://blackfire.io) to profile the code in CodeBuild, and you will find what is precisely slowing down the execution.

Answer (score 0):

My codebuild project provisioning time was very high because of using ancient standard containers. after i upgraded to latest container, the provisioning time improved 5x. Maybe unrelated to the original post but may help folks who are suffering from bad codebuild performance because of high provisioning time